# How to express 踏实 accurately?

Tags: translation, word-choice, vocabulary

What I want to say is "我是一个踏实的人", but I am not able to think out an accurate word or phrase to say that, thank you!

Comment: I am voting to close as this currently reads like a question that requires comprehensive knowledge of _English_ (i.e. "how do I effectively express this in English"), rather than Chinese (e.g. "what does this term mean exactly").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

踏实 seems to have two groups of meanings:

[1]

- dependable; sure and steady
- at ease; free from anxiety; having peace
  of mind

[2]

- practical; realistic; pragmatic
- down-to-earth

When it comes to describing people, I'd choose "dependable" or "down-to-earth" depending on which meaning you need. If you could provide some more context, it would help in choosing the best word.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is "pragmatic"

"我是一个踏实的人" - "I am a pragmatic person."

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pragmatic

Comment: 踏實 most likely came from a common phrase 腳踏實地 ( be practical)